# How can I embed a video to share on tumblr

Tags: tumblr

I want to share a video onTumbler

I am using this code to embed the video:

```
<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=myurl&amp;name=Test&amp;description=test&amp;embed=videourl"> share </a>
```

It displays a thumbnail of image but video does not play on tumbler its redirect to video URL

So i want to play this video on tumbler without it redirecting to the URL.

Comment: Surely this is a question about Tumblr rather than programming..

Comment: You just wanting to use this hyperlink to bring the user to the video or are you wanting the video to be separate from the page it is referenced from?

Comment: @JamesHunt I believe the op is trying to reference the video from tumbler on his page without taking the user to the actual location of the page. This would, however slightly, involve programming on the level of html or js.

Comment: Half is question is worded as embedding a video FROM Tumblr TO a page, the other half is worded as embedding a video FROM a page ONTO Tumblr. The latter is to do with Tumblr post formatting, which is mostly automated. The former requires knowledge of the video file type to know whether it requires an embedded player too.

Comment: @dipakk James Hunt is correct, can you add some more information and clean up your question a little bit to clarify your intention and the expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

From your wording it sounds like you have your own host and you're trying to share the videos from that host onto Tumblr.

Assuming this is true, try this:

Put this anywhere in the `<body>` of the page the video is on:

```
<script src="http://platform.tumblr.com/v1/share.js"></script>
```

Add this where you want the button to appear:

```
<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/video?embed=<?php echo urlencode(INSERT_EMBED_CODE_HERE) ?>&caption=<?php echo urlencode(INSERT_CAPTION_HERE) ?>" title="Share on Tumblr" style="display:inline-block; text-indent:-9999px; overflow:hidden; width:20px; height:20px; background:url('https://platform.tumblr.com/v1/share_4.png') top left no-repeat transparent;">Share on Tumblr</a>
```

Remember to replace the embed code and caption to whatever you use for that info on your site.